# adding fonts to photoshop CS6 run with wine

Tags: wine, fonts, photoshop

I have photoshop CS6 installed and working on Wine1.7. It's actually surprisingly smooth. The only issue I have now is that the fonts are a bit limited, and I'm not sure if it's an issue with wine or with the photoshop installation. I tried copying some fonts to the `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts/` directory but they are not appearing in photoshop.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

For those still searching for a solution in '17, you should install to the same wineprefix with wine or playonlinux's run exe in this virtual drive function (configure > Miscellaneous / Run a .exe ...) the program from this site:
http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php#Download

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

you should click on the font , then click install and make restart for the program .